# Getting admin consent in Microsoft Azure portal

Tags: azure, api, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am wondering why there ain't no button on my azure console where I can grant admin consent:

[image]

while it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you an admin?

Answer (score 3):

Well the obvious answer is - you do not have permissions to do that.

> To grant admin consent to permissions on Microsoft Graph and Azure AD
>   Graph, you need global administrator privileges.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#prerequisites